# Textmate toggle collapse/expand CSS rule command?

Tags: css, command, textmate, toggle

Does anyone know of a **command** (not a macro) for [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) / [E Text Editor](http://e-texteditor.com/) / [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/) / *etc*. that will collapse a multi-line CSS rule down to one line **OR**, if the rule is already on one line, expand it out to multi-line? I already know about code folding and that's not what I require - I need to be able to toggle the rules between single and multi-line and have them be edited and saved like that.

For example, if I have this:

```
h1 {font-size:3em;line-height:1;margin-bottom:0.5em;}
```

I would like to be able to place my cursor anywhere within the rule, hit a keyboard shortcut and it would turn into this:

```
h1 {
  font-size:3em;
  line-height:1;
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
```

On hitting the shortcut again, it would convert back into single-line.

Does anything like this exist? Does anyone have any code that does something similar I could repurpose (ideally Ruby)? Does anyone know if this is even possible in Textmate?

**Update**: it seems that CSS rule collapsing and expanding is [implemented as a pair of macros](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/CSS.tmbundle/Macros/) in Textmate. However, this isn't toggling and it also doesn't work in E Text Editor (which doesn't support macros). Not sure whether it works in Redcar. Is it possible to implement something similar as a command that can do toggling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating my own command to do this. [Grab it here](http://code.google.com/p/ebundles/source/browse/trunk/Bundles/CSS.tmbundle/Commands/Toggle+Single-line+and+Multi-line.tmCommand?spec=svn270&r=270).

There is a limitation in that for the command to work, the cursor has to be in whitespace within a rule declaration; i.e., not in a property/value pair scope. I've found placing the cursor just inside the opening brace to be a good place to trigger the command from.

If anyone knows how to select a parent scope that would be neat.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS bundle `ctrl + opt + Q` will collapse the currently selected rule into 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

Appending to Mark Story's answer, `ctrl + Q` does the opposite, turning a single line of CSS into nicely formatted CSS.